# Salesforce Toolkit 20.0 API Create Record: "Required Field Missing: [Student__c]"

Tags: php, salesforce

I am trying to create a new record in Salesforce using the Toolkit 20.0 PHP API. The object has a master-detail relationship field and, every time I try to create a new record in this object, I get an error stating that: "Required Field Missing: [field_name__c]". I am passing the 18-digit Salesforce ID to that field so I don't understand why it thinks it's missing.

```
$payment = new stdclass();
$payment->Bill_Amount__c = sprintf("%.2f", (int)$billamount);
$payment->Customer_Name__c = $debitcustname;
$payment->Student__c = $contact->records[0]->Id;
$payment->Transaction_Date__c = $transactiondate;

$createResponse = $sf->create($payment, 'Student_Payment__c');
```

When I var_dump $payment, I get the following object which looks correct to me:

```
object(stdClass)#7 (8) {
  ["Student__c"]=>
  string(18) "0033D00000NGoNNQA1"
  ["Bill_Amount__c"]=>
  string(6) "100.00"
  ["Customer_Name__c"]=>
  string(6) "SAMUEL"
  ["Transaction_Date__c"]=>
  string(20) "2017-01-01T00:00:00Z"
}
```

I've also checked my wsdl.xml file and the field, Student__c, is present.

```
<element name="Student__c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID"/>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the issue was that the first argument for the create method needs to be an array. Wrapping the $payment variable in brackets fixed the issue.

```
$payment = new stdclass();
$payment->Bill_Amount__c = sprintf("%.2f", (int)$billamount);
$payment->Customer_Name__c = $debitcustname;
$payment->Student__c = $contact->records[0]->Id;
$payment->Transaction_Date__c = $transactiondate;

$createResponse = $sf->create([$payment], 'Student_Payment__c');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually creating the record via Workbench or Salesforce Dev Console?

Alternatively I would create a debug log in Salesforce and then debug the before insert trigger for the Student_Payment__c object.

What you are doing should technically be working, might be some code inside a Salesforce trigger that is causing an issue or a validation rule setup for the Custom Object.

Comment: I just put it through Workbench with no problem. I did have to change the formatting of the Date, but I'm still getting the same "Required Field Missing" error.

Comment: And the log file? What do the logs say when you debug it?